# Android - Chromecast subtitles NanoHttpd

Tags: android, casting, cors

I successfully stream a video with NanoHttpd from my Android app to a local ip to play it on chromecast. 
Now I want to add subtitles, I have local .vtt file on my sdcard and I'm trying to also steam it on NanonHttpd on a different port.
Anyway I'm unable to see subtitles. I correctly implemented CORS on both video and subtitles local ips. 
If I type the subtitles ip on my browser, vtt file is displayed successfully.

Here my code snipped when I set substitles on MediaInfo:

```
  MediaTrack englishSubtitle = new MediaTrack.Builder(1 /* ID */,
                MediaTrack.TYPE_TEXT)
                .setName("English Subtitle")
                .setSubtype(MediaTrack.SUBTYPE_SUBTITLES)
                .setContentId(ipdeviceForSubs)
                .setLanguage("en-US")
                .build();

        MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, contentUri.getLastPathSegment());

        mSelectedMedia = new MediaInfo.Builder(ipdeviceForVideo != null ? ipdeviceForVideo : contentUri.toString())
                .setContentType("video/*")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
                .setMediaTracks(Arrays.asList(englishSubtitle))
                .build();
```

And this is my NanoHttpd webserver implementation for subtitles

```
  public class WebserverSubtitles extends NanoHTTPD {
    public WebserverSubtitles() throws IOException {

        super(8081);
    }


    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public NanoHTTPD.Response serve(String uri, Method method, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> parms, Map<String, String> files) {
        try {         
            FileInputStream localFileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/Download/v.vtt");
            NanoHTTPD.Response localResponse = new NanoHTTPD.Response(NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.OK, "text/vtt", localFileInputStream);
            localResponse.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            localResponse.addHeader("content-type", "text/vtt");
            return localResponse;
        } catch (Exception localException) {
            localException.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: When you turn on logging on the receiver, what do you see in the console?

Comment: I'm currenty using default receiver, not able to see logs

Comment: If I use this as contentId of my mediatrack subtitle are working correctly: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/CastVideos/tracks/DesigningForGoogleCast-en.vtt        I copied same exact file on my sd, streamed it with NanoHttpd with CORS support and nothing.. serve method of NanoHttpd webservice is not event called. If I open the same local address in browser vtt file is displayed correctly and serve method is called. It looks like local subtitle address is never called by cast api.

Comment: I suspect one of the two could be the issue: CORS was not implemented correctly (what does curl -v <URL> states for the headers of both video and tracks)? or the other possibility os that it may need https when tracks are added to the mix (which would then fail in your scenario). You can register a styled receiver to see the logs and that should be helpful to identify the issue.

Comment: I tried curl -v MYURL and I get this headers: * Rebuilt URL to: 192.168.1.101:8081/
*   Trying 192.168.1.101...
* Connected to 192.168.1.101 (192.168.1.101) port 8081 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.101:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
< Content-Type: text/vtt
< Date: Mon, 12 Sep 2016 07:33:09 GMT
< Content-Type: text/vtt
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 49532   I'm required to use https to stream subtitles? For video I use http and vtt from google server are working correctly

Comment: As I suggested earlier, register a Styled receiver so you can look at the console logs.

Comment: I've debugged with styled receiver:   insecure Text Track 'http://192.168.1.101:8081/v.vtt'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.    It looks like I have to use https. Strange thing is that video stream is not on https, it have the same log warning and it works fine. Do you think I will have to use https also for video?

Comment: You may but I am not sure, can't recall the details.

Comment: it was a probelm with .htaccess file misproperly configured on my server, thanks for your hints

Answer (score 0):

```
resp= newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.OK, MIME_PLAINTEXT ,"success");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3628800");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");




        resp.setChunkedTransfer(true);
return resp;
```

You have to add cors support at NanoHttpd server like above